# How do devices make themselves available for the outside world?

Tags: networking, ip, iot

this might be a stupid question, but I couldn't find anything on the web.

I am wondering, how certain IoT devices sometimes make themselves available to the outside world, without me having to open any ports etc. on my Router.

For example: I connect my Phillips Hue Bridge to my Router and somehow if I activate it in the app, I can control it from anywhere.

How does this work? I am trying to build something similar, so thats why I'm asking.

If you dont understand what I mean let me know, maybe I can describe it a little bit better then.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: **1)** upnp automated port forwarding (will not work in case your router does not get white IP for WAN interface), **2)** [UDP NAT traversal ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN) - may not work in some cases,  **3)** command(rendezvous) server with device keeping persistent outgoing connection (most reliable way but requires extra resources for rendezvous server compared to first two methods).

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny Rendezvous would be something like a server which for example keeps websockets to all clients open? Would that be a realistic scenario?

Comment: you have no choice really so question "Would that be realistic scenario?" is irrelevant. BTW, I did not mean websocket but it is indeed one of suitable technologies.